# For $T\in L(V,W)$, prove that there are bases such that $M(T)$ is 1 on the first dim range $T$ elements of the diagonal and zero everywhere else.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, solution-verification, linear-transformations

I'd like to solve the following problem from Chapter 3, "Linear Maps", section 3.C "Matrices", from Axler's *Linear Algebra Done Right*.

> 3. Suppose $V$ and $W$ are finite-dimensional and $T\in L(V,W)$. Prove
>    that there exist a basis of $V$ and a basis of $W$ such that with
>    respect to these bases, all entries of $M(T)$ are $0$ except that the
>    entries in row $j$, column $j$, equal 1 for $1\leq j\leq$ dim range
>    $T$.

Let dim $V=n$ and dim $W=m$.

It seems to me that there is an easy case that occurs when $m\geq n$ In this case, we can reduce the set of vectors $Tv_1,...,Tv_n \in $ range $T$ to a basis of dimension $l\leq n$.

Without loss of generality, assume this basis is formed by the vectors

$$Tv_1,...,Tv_l$$

Extend these vectors to a basis of $W$

$$Tv_1,...,Tv_l,w_1,...,w_{m-l}$$

Then, the matrix of $T$ is $m$ by $n$ and has the desired properties.

I saw a solution on a website and it only contained this first case. But is there not a second case?

**My question is about the second case.** Namely, if $m<n$.

$T$ is given.

Again, let's call dim range $T=l$.

We know that

$$\mathrm{dim\ null}\ T +\mathrm{dim\ range}\ T=\mathrm{dim}\ V$$

$$\mathrm{dim\ null}\ T + l = n$$

Thus, since $$l= \text{dim range}\ T\leq m<n=\text{dim}\ V$$

then dim null $T=n-l\geq 1$.

Of the $n$ vectors $v_1, ...,v_n$, $n-l$ are in the nullspace.

Suppose $v_1,...,v_l$ are not in the nullspace and $v_{l+1},...,v_n$ are.

Then, for every vector $v\in V$ we have

$$v=\sum_{i=1}^n c_i v_i$$

and so

$$Tv=\sum_{i=1}^n c_i Tv_i$$

$$=\sum_{i=1}^l c_i Tv_i$$

and so range $T=\text{ span }(Tv_1, ...,Tv_l)$. Since dim range $T=l$ and there are $l$ vectors in $(Tv_1, ..., Tv_l)$ it is a basis for range $T$.

Now we expand this basis into a basis for $W$

$$(Tv_1, ...,Tv_l,u_1,...,u_{m-l})$$

The matrix of $T$ relative to $(v_1,...,v_n)$ and $(Tv_1, ...,Tv_l,u_1,...,u_{m-l})$ has the desired properties.

**Is this proof correct?**

Comment: No. You haven't actually defined what the vectors $v_1,\ldots,v_n$ are. Just because you have $n$ vectors doesn't mean you have a basis. And even if you have a basis, it's not true in general that nullity many of them will be in the null space. You're essentially assuming what you're trying to prove, with other needless gymnastics.

Comment: Indeed. Moreover, in your first case you only constructed some basis for $W,$ none for $V.$ And in your second case, your claim "Of the $n$ vectors $v_1, ...,v_n$, $n-l$ are in the nullspace" has no reason to hold if you don't choose the $v_i$'s carefully.

Comment: You don't need to consider these 2 cases. Take a basis $(v_k,\dots,v_n)$ of $\operatorname{null}(T),$ complete it into a basis $(v_1,\dots,v_n)$ of $V,$ prove that $(w_i:=T(v_i))_{1\le i<k}$ is a basis of $\operatorname{range}(T),$ and complete it into a basis $(w_1,\dots,w_m)$ of $W.$

Comment: In the second base, what if I say: Let $v_{l+1},...v_n$ be a basis of the null space of $T$. Expand this basis by $l$ vectors $v_1,...,v_l$ to form a basis of $V$. Can I build this specific basis in this manner? As for the first case, can I not just specify that $v_1,...,v_n$ is any basis of $V$?

Answer (score 1):

There are essentially two ways to construct the required base of $V$ and $W$, which are "dual" to each other, starting either in $V$ or $W$. Since the previous answer started in $V$, I'll give the dual construction, starting in $W$:

**The dual proof**:

By starting with a basis of $\alpha(V)$ and extending it to a basis of $W$ we may find a basis $\{w_1,\ldots,w_m\}$ of $W$ such that $\{w_1,\ldots,w_r\}$ is a basis of $\alpha(V)$ ($1\leq r \leq m$).

Now pick vectors $v_1,\ldots,v_r \in V$ satisfying $\alpha(v_i)=w_i$, $1\leq i\leq r$ and set $S=\text{span}\{v_1,\ldots,v_r\}$. It is immediate from the definition of the $v_i$s that $\alpha_{|S}\colon S\to W$ is an injective linear map with image $\alpha(V)$.

Next we claim that $V = S\oplus K$, where $K=\text{ker}(\alpha)$. For this, first note that $K\cap S = \text{ker}(\alpha_{|S})=\{0\}$. Next, for any $v\in V$, we have $\alpha(v)\in \alpha(V)=\alpha(S)$ hence there is some $s \in S$ such that $\alpha(s)=\alpha(v)$, and thus $v = s+(v-s) \in S+K$ as required.

But now picking a basis of $K$, say $\{u_1,\ldots,u_n\}$ we see that the matrix of $\alpha$ with respect to the basis $\{v_1,\ldots,v_r\}\cup\{u_1,\ldots,u_n\}$ of $V$ and $\{w_1,\ldots,w_r\}\cup\{e_1,\ldots,e_m\}$ of $W$ has the required form.

$\blacksquare$

Note that the theorem can be phrased as saying that the only "invariant" of a linear map $\alpha\colon V\to W$ is its rank, *i.e.* the only property of a matrix representing $\alpha$ with respect to choices of bases for $V$ and $W$ which is independent of the choice of basis made, is the rank of that matrix. In the language of group actions, this says that the action of $\mathrm{GL}(V)\times\mathrm{GL}(W)$ on $L(V,W)$ has $\dim(V)+1$ orbits, where an orbit is the set of all linear maps of a given rank $k$, where $0\leq k \leq \dim(V)$.

Moreover, the theorem also implies the rank-nullity theorem, namely that $\dim(V) = \dim(\alpha(V))+ \dim(\text{ker}(\alpha))$ (indeed in the proof above, this is contained in the step where we check that $V=S\oplus K$).

Finally, the most concrete way to prove the theorem is to use the methods we use to solve (homogeneous) linear systems of equations: If you are given an explicit linear map, then it will almost surely be given in terms of its matrix $A$ with respect to some bases of $V$ and $W$.  If the $j$-th column has $a_{ij}\neq 0$ and $a_{kl}=0$ for all $(k,l)$ with $k<i$, we can move the first $i-1$ rows of $A$ to become the last $i-1$ rows, and swap columns $1$ and $i$ (these operations correspond to reordering the given bases of $V$ and $W$). Now by using row operations we may modify $A$ so that its first column becomes equal to $(1,0,\ldots,0)^\intercal$, where the row operations correspond to modifying the basis of $W$. Similarly, we can use column operations to modify the first row of into the form $(1,0,\ldots,0)$, giving a matrix of the form
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{c|ccc}1 & 0 & \ldots & 0
\\
\hline
 0 & & & \\ \vdots & & A_1 & \\ 0 & & & \end{array}\right)
$$
Now if $A_1=0$ we are done, otherwise we iterate -- find a column with a non-zero entry in the highest row in which $A_1$ has nonzero entries, and perform the same operations as before. Since this process must terminate in at most $\text{min}\{n,m\}$ steps, the result follows.

In essence, in the concrete argument, one starts with bases of $V$ and $W$ already given to you, and show how they can be modified to yield bases of $V$ and $W$ with the required property. In the more abstract argument, one gives oneself the freedom to choose bases for various subspaces.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments to the original question, I will try to fix the original proof.

First, however, I would like to try to write the simpler proof suggested by Anne Bauval.

Here it is

Let's first define some variables:

- $T:V\to W$
- dim range $T=l$
- dim $V=n$
- dim $W=m$

We know that

$$\text{dim null}\ T=\text{dim} V-\text{dim range}\ T=n-l$$

Let $(u_1,...,u_{n-l})$ be a basis of null $T$.

Expand this to a basis of $V$: $(u_1,...,u_{n-l},v_1,...,v_l)$.

Then, for any $v\in V$, we can write

$$v=\sum_{i=1}^{n-l} a_i u_i +\sum_{i=1}^l b_i v_i$$

$$Tv=\sum_{i=1}^l b_iTv_i=\sum_{i=1}^l b_iw_i$$

Thus, the vectors $(w_1,...,w_l)$ span range $T$. Since dim range $T=l$ then these vectors are a basis for range $T$.

Now, $l\leq m$ and $l\leq n$.

Thus, it is always the case that $l\leq m$, which means that either $(w_1,...,w_l)$ is a basis for $W$ (if $l=m$) or we can expand this basis to become a basis of $W$

$$(w_1,...,w_m)$$

In any case, we end up with a basis of $W$ and when we map the basis $(u_1,...,u_{n-l},v_1,...,v_l)$ using $T$ the resulting vectors in $W$ do not involve multiples of $w_{l+1},...,w_m$.

In other words, as we've seen, the vectors $v_1,...,v_l$ get mapped to $w_1,...,w_l$ and $u_1,...,u_{n-l}$ get mapped to zero.

If we reorder the basis of $V$ to

$$v_1,...,v_l,u_1,...,u_{n-l}$$

then we get the exact matrix that is asked for.